# Merging Multidimensional array on php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have a like below which has duplicate data for provider details I want to merge the data into id '22' in PHP language

```
{
                        "id": "22",
                        "name": "Respite",
                        "provider_id": "7",
                        "is_current": 0,
                        "is_saca": 0,
                        "is_navigator": 0,
                        "providerDetails": {
                            "id": "7",
                            "name": "Pankaj ji Service Provider4",
                            "email": "testqa9030@gmail.com",
                            "phone_number": "975-392-6267",
                            "accepts_medicaid": "0",
                            "accepts_private_pay": "0",
                            "address": "ujj",
                            "additional_info": "",
                            "telehealth": "yes",
                            "speaking": "no",
                            "providerService": [
                                "22"
                            ],
                            "locationService": [
                                "5"
                            ],
                            "provider_rating": [],
                            "provider_avgrating": [
                                "4"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "22",
                        "name": "Respite",
                        "provider_id": "1",
                        "is_current": 0,
                        "is_saca": 0,
                        "is_navigator": 0,
                        "providerDetails": {
                            "id": "1",
                            "name": "Service 1",
                            "email": "",
                            "phone_number": "",
                            "accepts_medicaid": "1",
                            "accepts_private_pay": "1",
                            "address": "Hello world",
                            "additional_info": "This is",
                            "telehealth": "yes",
                            "speaking": "yes",
                            "providerService": [
                                "4",
                                "7",
                                "22",
                                "23",
                                "27"
                            ],
                            "locationService": [
                                "1",
                                "2",
                                "4"
                            ],
                            "provider_rating": [
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "2",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "4",
                                    "comment": "wwww",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:12:34.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "4",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "5",
                                    "comment": "wwww",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:13:53.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "6",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "5",
                                    "comment": "dddddd",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:14:04.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "8",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "5",
                                    "comment": "dddddd",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:14:20.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "10",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "4",
                                    "comment": "dddddd",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:15:12.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "12",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "4",
                                    "comment": "ddddddsss",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:15:30.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "14",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "5",
                                    "comment": "dddd",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:17:40.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "16",
                                    "user_id": "12",
                                    "first_name": "Rishabh",
                                    "last_name": "Jain",
                                    "rating": "3",
                                    "comment": "ddddd",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T09:18:32.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "18",
                                    "user_id": "11",
                                    "first_name": "Navigator",
                                    "last_name": "spans",
                                    "rating": "3",
                                    "comment": "test",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T11:06:55.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "20",
                                    "user_id": "11",
                                    "first_name": "Navigator",
                                    "last_name": "spans",
                                    "rating": "3",
                                    "comment": "zzzz",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T11:08:59.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "22",
                                    "user_id": "11",
                                    "first_name": "Navigator",
                                    "last_name": "spans",
                                    "rating": "4",
                                    "comment": "zzzz",
                                    "created_at": "2022-03-31T11:09:44.000Z"
                                },
                                {
                                    "provider_feedback_id": "42",
                                    "user_id": "11",
                                    "first_name": "Navigator",
                                    "last_name": "spans",
                                    "rating": "4",
                                    "comment": "sssss",
                                    "created_at": "2022-04-01T05:49:10.000Z"
                                }
                            ],
                            "provider_avgrating": [
                                "4"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_unique()

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```